# Dividir un campo/Columna en varias, ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Una duda, tengo una tabla con una columna que arroja información (identificador+Numero de empleado) de instructores.

Necesito separarlo en mi consulta para hacer un Join con las tablas correspondientes donde arroje su nombre completo, solo que no se cual sea la función para separarlo.

Ejemplo del campo.

```
|Usuario Ultima Act|

INSTRUCTOR - 8006490
```

Yo necesito saber como dividir esa columna para que quede como la siguiente:

```
Usuario Ultima Act  | No.EmpleadoUsuario Ultima Act
----------------------------------------------------

INSTRUCTOR          | 8006490
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `instr` para determinar la posición del guión y dividir la columna en dos:

```
SELECT RTrim(SUBSTR(t.campo, 1, INSTR(t.campo, '-')-1)) AS Usuario,
       LTrim(SUBSTR(t.campo, INSTR(t.campo, '-')+1)) AS NoEmpleado
  FROM TuTabla t
```

Comment: Mil gracias! Eso sirvió :)

Comment: Me alegra, un gusto ;)

Comment: Amigo, Otra duda, para ésto quise partir estas columnas debido a que el campo de "NoEmpleado" necesito hacer un JOIN con la tabla de PERSONA para poder traerme su "Nombre completo", es esto posible? ya que no estaría referenciando a una tabla si no a una columna. Es decir poder hacer un Join con PERSONA donde el NoEmpleado sea el mismo de la columna "NoEmpleado" que acabamos de partir.

Comment: Claro que es posible, puedes hacer esto en la condición del `join`, algo como: `left join Empleado e on e.NoEmpleado = LTrim(SUBSTR(t.campo, INSTR(t.campo, '-')+1))`

Comment: Perfecto me funcionó te agradezco mucho :D